# Trig integral evaluations with Complex analysis:Show $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{5 + 3\cos\theta}\ d\theta = \frac{2\pi}{9} $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am currently trying to evaluate this integral with residues but I'm not quite there. The questions asks me to show

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{5 + 3\cos\theta}\ d\theta = \frac{2\pi}{9} $$

So I let $z = e^{i\theta}$ and so $\frac {dz}{iz} = d\theta$

I let $\sin^2\theta = \frac {z^2 + z^{-2} -2}{-4}$ but I can't seem to get the answer! Are there any other tips to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\sin^2 \theta}{5+3\cos\theta} \ d\theta$

$z = e^{i\theta}\\
dz = ie^{i\theta}\ d\theta\\
d\theta = \frac 1{i z} \ dz$

$\sin \theta  = \frac {1}{2i}(z - z^{-1})\\
\sin^2 \theta  = \frac {1}{4}(2-z^2 - z^{-2})\\
\cos\theta = \frac 1{2}(z + z^{-1})$

$\oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{2-z^2 - z^{-2}}{(4iz)(5 + \frac 12 (3z + 3z^{-1}))} \ dz\\
\oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{-z^4 +2z^2 - 1 }{(2i)(z^2)(3z + 1)(z+3)} \ dz\\
\frac 1{2i}\oint_{|z| = 1} -\frac 13 - \frac 1{3z^2} + \frac {10}{9z} - \frac {8}{9(z+\frac 13)} + \frac  8{9(z+3)} \ dz$

$z = 0, z =-\frac 13$ are the only poles inside the countour

$\pi (\frac {10}{9} - \frac {8}{9}) = \frac {2\pi}{9}$

Comment: Urgh parfracs. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Oh true! The CIF and the corollary to the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to use partial fractions.  You could also say $f(z) = \frac {-z^4 + 2z^2 - 1}{(3z+1)(z+ 3)}, g(z) = \frac {-z^4 + 2z^2 - 1}{3z^2(z+3)}$ and by the Cauchy integral theorem it evaluates to $\pi (f'(0) + g(-\frac 13))$  But I don't know if that is any easier. (had an error last time I posted)